# Crash in debug mode along with CDB process termination, but release mode is fine

Tags: qt, qt-creator, release-mode, debug-mode

My application builds and runs fine in ***Release*** mode. However, in ***Debug*** mode, my application crashes. When trying to use debugger to pinpoint the crash cause, such error is received:

> Qt Creator unexpected CDB exit
> The CDB process terminated

[image: Error screenshot]

What could possibly be the problem cause?

### UPDATE

I built and deployed the application in *Debug* mode and then tried to run the executable by command like:

```sh
C:\Users\m3\Documents\deployment_folder>.\application.exe
```

and I received this message:

> The code execution cannot be proceed because `tbb_debug.dll` was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

For some reason, `tbb.dll` can be found in *Release* mode but `tbb_debug.dll` cannot be found in *debug* mode. Although all TBB DLLs are in the same directory. Not sure why ...

[image: Screenshot]

### UPDATE

I'm adding TBB to my project with QMake like this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += deps/tbb-2020.3-win/tbb/include

# Looks like absolute path works for LIBS, but NOT relative path
win32: CONFIG (release, debug|release): {
    LIBS += -LC:\Users\m3\repos\myapp\deps\tbb-2020.3-win\tbb\lib\intel64\vc14 \
            -ltbb \
            -ltbb_preview \
            -ltbbbind \
            -ltbbmalloc \
            -ltbbmalloc_proxy \
            -ltbbproxy
} else: win32: CONFIG (debug, debug|release): {
    LIBS += -LC:\Users\m3\repos\myapp\deps\tbb-2020.3-win\tbb\lib\intel64\vc14 \
            -ltbb_debug \
            -ltbb_preview_debug \
            -ltbbbind_debug \
            -ltbbmalloc_debug \
            -ltbbmalloc_proxy_debug \
            -ltbbproxy_debug
} else: unix: { # Linux and mac
    # TODO: add correct path to LIBS +=
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved by **manually copying** TBB DLLs next to the application executable.

Copy from `... /tbb-2020.3-win/tbb/bin/intel64/vc14/*.dll` to executable location.

#### On why release mode worked

I think some 3rd party application has already added `tbb.dll` to may PATH environment variable. But `tbb_debug.dll` is *not* added to PATH by any application. Just a guess ...

Comment: You don't add a file to the PATH environment variable, you add a folder. If both dll's are in the same folder but the debug dll is not found, only thing I can think of is that the application gets started with a different user having a different PATH. If you want to determine the root cause, download procmon from sysinternals and have it monitor your release and debug build.You should be able to find where the release build dll gets loaded and where it searches for the debug dll.